# How to bound chances of edges from a set in a random matching?

Tags: probability, birthday

suppose I have n nodes, and I pick at random a partial matching (i.e. disjoints edges) containing
$$\alpha n$$
edges.

How can I show the probability of having at least one edge which both of its endpoints are in the first
$$c = \epsilon\sqrt{n/\alpha}$$
nodes is at least
$$\Omega(\epsilon^2)$$

Is it implied somehow by the birthday paradox?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is no a good idea to put each and every mathematical expression within a pair of `$$`'s.

Answer (score 0):

Good catch, it is basically the birthday paradox. Here is a proof sketch -- I can expand some of the details if necessary.

---

First, the number of matched vertices among the first $c$ vertices is tightly concentrated around $2\alpha c$ -- in a way that can be quantified by standard Chernoff bounds. That way, you can basically reduce to the following problem: given a random perfect matching of $2\alpha n$ vertices, what is the probability that there is an edge contained in a (fixed) set of $2\alpha c$ vertices?

One way to see this distribution is to first generate for each vertex independently a random integer between $1$ and $\alpha n$ (which is the classical birthday paradox setting), and then condition on these integers corresponding to a matching. Observe that the conditioning only makes collisions *more* likely. In other words, the probability that there is *no* edge contained in the set of $2\alpha c$ vertices is at most
$$1\left(1-\frac{1}{\alpha n}\right)\ldots\left(1-\frac{2\alpha c-1}{\alpha n}\right)\le \exp(-K\alpha c^2/n),$$
for some constant $K$. Picking $c=\varepsilon\sqrt{n/\alpha}$ gives the desired bound.

Comment: Thanks! intuitively I can see why in the first $c$ nodes I'll have around $\alpha c$ nodes participating in the match, but I'm not sure how to prove it formally - as they are not really chosen independently at random.